# WCF System Diagnostics generates additional logs with GUID

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, web-config

I added logging to ours WCF service hosted on IIS using system diagnostics.
 Problem is it generates to many additional files. 
Those files are created according to pattern: *some_GUID_log_file_name.* 
I do not understand what have I done wrong ?

To be more specific:

1. This is not 1 service/endpoint. We need to define exactly 3 soap
   sevices.
2. It is compiled into 1 DLL.
3. There is only 1 web.config.
4. And so far it is added just for 1 from those 3 services.

Example of files generated:

```
19c2274c-56d1-4260-8efc-95fe9a3ca7bctracelog.log
1f7acecf-b2f9-48da-80d4-97014acd3119tracelog.log
45955050-6b7b-4a7d-9ec8-be751ded437ctracelog.log
5fb4f509-0e6d-4ee7-ab20-66f9bfbf31aftracelog.log
a57f9c35-62b4-491e-8db8-354cd6c40cectracelog.log
ec9ba7c6-2dc3-4761-89cf-9f4f421444fatracelog.log
tracelog.log
```

Web.conifg

```
 <source name="TraceLog"  switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="textfileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="logs\tracelog.log" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
```

TraceSource is initialized in applicaion.

```
private static TraceSource _traceSource = new TraceSource("TraceLog", SourceLevels.All);
...
_traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 10, "some trace");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUIDs are a feature of the `TextWriterTraceListener`. Before it attempts to write to the file it calls the internal method `EnsureWriter`. If you peek into that with ILSpy you'll find this implementation:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            this.writer = new StreamWriter(path, true, encodingWithFallback, 4096);
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + text;
            path = Path.Combine(directoryName, text);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

This code tries to create a `StreamReader` for the configured filename. If that fails, for example because the file is open, it generates new name with a GUID in it and retries. It does this because it desperately wants to write the content.

This can easily happen in web scenario's, specially during start-up/re-cycle of an `AppDomain`. While one `AppDomain` is shutting down but still logging its errors the new `AppDomain` starts and also starts logging. That race-condition leads to the creation of log-files with GUIDs. Rogue virusscanners can also be the source of this, as well as a system engineer that opens the file with a viewer that locks the file.

Instead of preventing this from happening you might want to consider merging the logfiles into one single file.
Another trick I use is to have multiple `TraceListeners` that log certain aspects of the app. You could do that per layer or per service for example.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Merging is not an option and multiple tracelisteners would be hard because we need to trace behavior in shared components. I guess we wil try log4net or other.